# Notation for a unit vector

Tags: notation, vectors

If I have a vector $\vec{v}$, is there a standard concise notation for the unit vector in the same direction of $\vec{v}$ that is $\frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}$?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: You can simply define one. But, to me, there seems no need to have one such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the notation
$$\hat v = \frac{v}{\|v\|_2}$$
is used. I've especially seen it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) and 3D-Graphics related articles containing math.

Comment: Indeed, if I see any notation to signify a vector has unit length (or a normalized vector), it's \hat. Not to say it's standard, but it's the only one I can ever recall seeing.

Comment: Why is there a subscript 2 in the denominator?

Comment: @nosyarg To clarify that we are talking about the euclidean norm.

Comment: Ok so it means the same thing as$\frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}$?

Comment: @nosyarg Yes, it's just cleaner.